# How to calculate a number of possible paths between two nodes on a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph with $N$ nodes. Every single node is **not** neccesarily connected to every other node on the graph, but we do know to which ones it is connected.

> How can I calculate a maximum number of different possible paths between any two nodes on a graph using [`dijkstras algorythm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) assuming the above is true?